# jQuery Datepicker disabled dates (Keith Wood's great)

Tags: jquery

I am using Keith Wood's great jQuery Datepicker plugin[jQuery Datepicker plugin](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

I want to disable past dates
Please help me out

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late, but in any case:

it's using these attributes

```
    startDate: '0d',
    minDate: 0,
```

the full example would be:

```
 $(".dateInput").calendarsPicker({
    calendar:
    $.calendars.instance('ummalqura', 'ar'),
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    startDate: '0d',
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (dates) {
        $(this).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

Comment: you can use this in your code   $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });  or checkout this 
http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/98/JQuery-Date-Picker-example-to-disable-previous-dates.aspx